# Can't use a locally modified Angular module inside another project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-module, angular-library, ngx-charts

I'm getting the following error when I `ng serve` (and I've already tried to clear cache, reinstall all modules and reboot the server)

```
Error: ../../../../angular/ngx-charts-master/ngx-charts-master/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts/lib/ngx-charts.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the dependency which declares NgxChartsModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc.
```

The full contextual background is that I've modified the source and posted a [pull request](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/pull/1613) but I don't know if/when the maintainers will accept it and I want to use the modified module in the meantime at least.

Of course I've tested the changes by using them through the internal demo app (with a couple of trivial, ad hoc changes) and it's all working fine. Then I build the dist with the

```
ng build @swimlane/ngx-charts
```

and it produced its output inside the dist folder `/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts/` from which I'm trying to import as shown above, at the beginning

### Further trying...

I've rewritten the import as

```
import { NgxChartsModule } from '../../../../../../angular/ngx-charts-master/ngx-charts-master/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts';
```

I deleted the standard entry in package.json and installed the module from my local folder

```
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "file:../../../../angular/ngx-charts-master/ngx-charts-master/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts",
```

Then I followed the instruction to install also the dev dependencies

```
"d3-array": "^2.9.1",
"d3-brush": "^2.1.0",
"d3-color": "^2.0.0",
"d3-format": "^2.0.0",
"d3-hierarchy": "^2.0.0",
"d3-interpolate": "^2.0.1",
"d3-scale": "^3.2.3",
"d3-selection": "^2.0.0",
"d3-shape": "^2.0.0",
"d3-time-format": "^3.0.0",
"d3-transition": "^2.0.0"
```

(copied from the project json in the internal lib of the module repository) but `ng serve` still fails with

```
Error: ../../../../angular/ngx-charts-master/ngx-charts-master/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts/lib/area-chart/area-chart.component.d.ts:2:29 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'd3-shape'. 'F:/Appl/angular/ngx-charts-master/ngx-charts-master/dist/swimlane/ngx-charts/node_modules/d3-shape/dist/d3-shape.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/d3-shape` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'd3-shape';`

2 import { CurveLinear } from 'd3-shape';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
```

### Note

I didn't mention, but now I suspect these warnings from the `npm run build:lib --prod` were relevant to the question

```
√ Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
√ Bundling to FESM2015
/ Bundling to UMDWARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-selection' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Selection'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-brush' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Brush'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-scale' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Scale'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-shape' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Shape'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-array' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Array'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-interpolate' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Interpolate'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-format' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Format'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-color' in output.globals – guessing 'd3_color'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-hierarchy' in output.globals – guessing 'd3Hierarchy'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'd3-time-format' in output.globals – guessing 'd3TimeFormat'
√ Bundling to UMD
√ Minifying UMD bundle
√ Writing package metadata
i Built @swimlane/ngx-charts

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Built Angular Package
 - from: F:\Appl\angular\ngx-charts-master\ngx-charts-master\projects\swimlane\ngx-charts
 - to:   F:\Appl\angular\ngx-charts-master\ngx-charts-master\dist\swimlane\ngx-charts
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried almost everything... finally I'm importing the source and it looks like it wants the project folder inside the root directory and not from a path outside it, so I copied the project folder from the module repository under the root of my app and pointed to it

```
import { NgxChartsModule } from '../projects/swimlane/ngx-charts/src/lib/ngx-charts.module';
```

At least, now my `ng serve` is running fine (so I'm happy enough with this solution/workaround)

### compiler options

I forgot to share the settings I had to update in `tsconfig.json`

```
"strict": false,
"noImplicitReturns": false,
```

and below

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
```

Anyway, as noted in my comment below, I haven't (yet) released my modified module to the users but the standard one with `percentageFormatting` to zero decimal places (that seems fair enough)

Comment: try to build the project as well, I have tried to use this package as well few days ago, but noticed it is already deprecated and isn't compatible with IVY

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan what is deprecated (any link to this notice)? It looks quite cool and very appreciated by my users, to be honest... I've delivered the standard version, not my locally modified one. I'm keeping the percentage format to zero decimal places, that is ok for my users (and I guess for everyone)

Comment: it means it isn't supported anymore. Maybe I was wrong? will let you know if I will find anything connected with this

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, but maybe this can be helpfull https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1540

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan maybe you mean that this `@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr` has been deprecated and it is in the angular.json in the section to build the library

Comment: I couldn't find anything connected with deprecation, but I have used another library because of deprecation and some build issues.